# can I get the all the scopes attached with access_token through Vimeo API?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

Can I check if user has allowed the scope,  asked while authorization.
So if access_token hasn't permission for certain scope then i could give some message to allow the scope & login page.
*alternate*
Can I set my app on vimeo such that it should not allow until user has scope what i needed.[image authorization checkbox unchecked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jo2mw.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the access token, the JSON also includes the scopes the authorized returned. You can read more details here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication#receiving-the-access-token-in-the-authentication-response